# Exporting QGIS basemaps as raster in ArcMap

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.0

I'm mapping a National Park in Malawi using QGIS as with the plugin I can get the images from Google Earth (I need to see the vegetation).

Since my supervisor is using ArcMap 10.0, do you know if it's possible to save the file with the maps I need (Malawi etc) so that she can open it in ArcMap?

I'm wondering if there's a way to save the maps as raster or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the QGIS main window (ie. not in print composer) you can choose File > Same as Image > TIF or TIFF format

This will save a TIFF file (image) and TIFFw file (TIFF world file, which contains georeferencing information for the image you just saved.

That will then go right back into QGIS and ArcMap. ArcMap warns about not knowing the spatial reference, but will draw it in the correct location.

Be advised though, that Google has a policy about not using their data for anything.  If you trace something using their imagery/data, it belongs to them!

You may want to use Bing. I do not think they have the same data restrictions.